# brew create traceur compiler and npm install -g

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, traceur

I'm trying to create a [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) formula that requires some npm modules to be installed.

I see that [npm is handled](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/dependency_collector.rb) by brew and external dependency so I want to download [traceur-compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) and then build it.

My formula goes like this:

```
class Traceur < Formula
  homepage "https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler"
  url "..."
  sha1 "..."
  version "1.0.0"

  # depends_on :node

  def install
    system "./configure",
                        "--disable-debug",
                          "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                          "--disable-silent-rules",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}"

    system "npm install -g"
    system "make"
  end

  test do
    system "false"
  end
end
```

I've downloaded the repo into the cache and set the SHA1 so it runs but it fails:

```
==> npm install -g
2014-11-26 15:49:30 +1100

npm install -g


READ THIS: http://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
```

Is it possible to install npm packages globally with homebrew?

Answer (score 0):

Read this https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md#specifying-gems-python-modules-etc-as-dependencies for how to do this correctly.